# HTML5 Sequence of grouping header and article

Tags: html

I got a question about the grouping headers together for an article. Which of the following is more suitable and is a good practice?

1. Should I group both `h1` and `h2` together in a `header` element then put it inside `article` element, or;
2. Group `h1` and `h2` together first then only go the `article` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) says, of the `<header>` element:

> The header element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element...When the nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element is the body element, then it applies to the whole page.

If you do not put them within sectioning content, they may be misinterpreted. Place them within sectioning content; in this case, an `<article>` element.

Comment: so is it mean body > article > header?